# SVG element with viewBox and preserveAspectRatio="none" with rect inside only scaling with width of container div

Tags: html, css, svg

In the codepen I have a svg element with these two attributes:

> preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 500 300"

The rect within the svg element is within range of 500x300.
When I change the width of the container div `.holder` in the css the rect does scale but setting height doesn't seem to affect it. It seems to want to perserve aspect ratio.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRBOdj?editors=1100

How would I make it so that the svg would always scale to fit within the `.holder` div?

Comment: Hi, try/use viewBox 100%.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It just throws away all scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Use both width and height for the svg

```css
.holder {
  height: 400px;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
<svg viewBox="0 54 500 246" height="400" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <g>
     <polyline fill="rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)" points="0, 245 44, 245 44, 190 47, 190 47, 245 91, 245 91, 136 98, 136 98, 245 132, 245 132, 136 136, 136 136, 190 139, 190 139, 136 142, 136 142, 245 196, 245 196, 190 199, 190 199, 245 243, 245 243, 136 250, 136 250, 245 284, 245 284, 136 287, 136 287, 190 291, 190 291, 136 294, 136 294, 245 348, 245 348, 136 351, 136 351, 190 395, 190 395, 54 398, 54 398, 81 401, 81 401, 245 436, 245 436, 136 439, 136 439, 190 443, 190 443, 136 446, 136 446, 245 500, 245 500, 136 500, 300 0, 300">     
     </polyline>
  </g>    
</svg>
</div>
```